# why does deltaY in scrollWheel method of NSView report often 0.0 when using multitouch pad?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have an `NSWindow` containing a subclassed `NSOpenGLView`. When using the wheel of a mouse, then every wheel step yields 0.1 if turning the wheel slowly. When using the multitouch pad of a macbook and scrolling slowly, then I get many events with deltaY of 0.0 and sporadically one with 0.3 or 0.4. Does anybody know where this comes from and how it can be switched off? When scrolling in a text editor with the multitouch pad it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by “switched off”? Such events are a natural result of tracking touches rather than integer increments of a scroll wheel, and if you’re correctly scaling by the delta they should have no effect.

If you need more complex control of scrolling behaviour, OS X 10.7 adds a new `NSEventPhase` type and `phase` property for distinguishing between different parts of a touch scroll event (I expect the 0-delta events correspond to `NSEventPhaseStationary`).

Comment: the problem is that 0-delta events are coming when i scroll a bit (i.e. two fingers on the multitouch pad and moving a bit). in a text editor or browser this results in a movement but i don't know how to move in my view when i get 0-delta events.

Comment: Ah, right. For more precision, use `scrollDeltaY` and `scrollDeltaX` (also new in Lion).

Comment: but i have snow leopard and i see that it works in other apps. so is there a solution for snow leopard?

Comment: According to [a recent exchange](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2011/Aug/msg00006.html) on the quartz-dev mailing list, this information can be extracted from the underlying `CGEvent`.